# NgIf Angular 4 with Json if 1 = img if 0 = "empty"

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to show an img if my web API is returning 1 and nothing if it is returning 0.

The strange thing with my code is when my API returns 1, that works, but when its "0" I've an error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Also, actually it returns assigned=0 but if assigned=0 then assignee doesn't appear at all in the JSON. I suppose the issue comes from here:

```
<td>
    <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[1].availability.assigned === 0; else noloading2;">
        <p>walou</p>
    </span>            
    <ng-template #noloading2>
        <div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
            {{user.data.apps.details[1].assignee.name}}
        </div>
    </ng-template> 
 </td>
```

Comment: It seems `user.data.apps.details[0].assignee` is undefined. check your `details` array response.

Comment: Thanks @anoop I checked it already and it returning assingned=0 but if assigned =0 then assignee doesn't appear at all in the Json..I suppose the issue comes from here...I update my post

Comment: It look like it's still parsing "else noloading" even if it's returning 0...

Comment: see this [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xmraUJ8JnyOI2hDMBGoa?p=preview) and compare your data model.

Comment: Many thanks @anoop but I found another way to make it work ;)

Comment: <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
                    <ng-template #noloading2>
                        {{user.data.apps.details[1].assignee.name}}
                    </ng-template>
                    <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.details[1].assigned===0;else noloading2;">
                        <img/>
                    </span>
                </td>